# JQuery ajax call blocks RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a view with an ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "CreateChecklistCopies",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(drivers),
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
        });
```

The controller action performs some tasks and redirects to the index method of the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateChecklistCopies([FromBody] object i_vm)
        {
            var tmp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChecklistCopyModel>>(i_vm.ToString());
            int result = _obj.AddChecklistCopies(tmp);
            
            if (result > 0)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { SuccessMessage = "Checklists were successfully duplicated." });            
            else 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ErrorMessage = "An error occurred when duplicating the checklist." });            
        }
```

The Index action is successfully executed but there's no forward to the index page happening:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index(string FilterCreator, string salesPersonFilter, string SuccessMessage, string ErrorMessage)
        {
            if (FilterCreator == null)
            {
                FilterCreator = User.Identity.Name.Split("\\")[1];
            }
            else if (FilterCreator.ToLower() == "all")
            {
                FilterCreator = null;
            }

            var checklists = _obj.GetChecklists(true, FilterCreator, salesPersonFilter);
            var salespersons = _obj.GetSalespersons();
            var chlVm = _mapper.Map<List<ChecklistModel>, List<ChecklistListViewModel>>(checklists);
            var ivm = new IndexViewModel
            {
                CheckLists = chlVm,
                Salespersons = salespersons,
                SuccessMessage = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SuccessMessage) ? SuccessMessage : "",
                ErrorMessage = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage) ? ErrorMessage  : ""
            };

            return View(ivm);
        }
```

I played around with the `async: false` tag in the ajax call but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: you cant redirect in a ajax call action.  you should return your data from `CreateChecklistCopies` and control redirect in JS insde ajax like `success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = data; //data mean your returned url
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `RedirectToAction` to action in an ajax call to redirect the entire page. Because the ajax response is limited to the ajax request scope only.

What you can do is return a json object instead of `RedirectToAction` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateChecklistCopies([FromBody] object i_vm)
{
    var tmp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChecklistCopyModel>>(i_vm.ToString());
    int result = _obj.AddChecklistCopies(tmp);
    
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(new JsonSerializerSettings());

    if (result > 0)
        result = Json(new { IsRedirect = True, RedirectUrl = '/controller/Index/...', SuccessMessage = "Checklists were successfully duplicated." });            
    else
        result = Json(new { IsRedirect = True, RedirectUrl = '/controller/Index/...', SuccessMessage = "An error occurred when duplicating the checklist." });

    return result;
}
```

Then in the ajax call do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "CreateChecklistCopies",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(drivers),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,   
}).done(function (response) {
    
    if (response != null) {
        
        window.location = response.RedirectUrl;
        
        //You can also use the IsRedirect  and SuccessMessage property as needed
        
    } else {
        alert('There was a problem processing the request.');
    }
}).fail(function () {
    alert('There was a problem processing the request.');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, with some minor tweaks it worked out for me. I just hate Javascript a little more every day \o/

Comment: @d00d Js is pretty powerful and at times it makes life easier too. Glad that I could help. Hope you dont mind upvoting the answer too? :)